# Since IOS 12, Candidates of Chinese input method will have ellipsis when longer than 2 word in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c

The Chinese candidates show truncation to ellipsis when there are enough space.

This issue is happened to my app. 
It can reproduce when input Chinese triggered by a common UITextField (main.m invoke the simplest AppDelegate, and directly invoke an empy viewcontroler with a UITextField).
But my app project is a big one, there must be some configs related to this issue, but I have tried a lot still failed to find it out.

```
@implementation ViewController
UITextField *_textField;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"测试输入";

    _textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    _textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    _textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    _textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    _textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    _textField.frame = CGRectMake(20, 90, self.view.frame.size.width-40, 100);
    _textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:_textField];
}
```

In IOS11 it works fine, but since 12, it comes up. Any body can help how to fix it, thank you very much.

Comment: You can view this image for more detail.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3140.png

Comment: it depends on which Input method you are using. I'm using Quick, no such problem.

Comment: This issue will appear when using the default Chinese input method in IOS, and it will not reproduce when using input xunfei 讯飞 input method. But most people use the default one, so I must fix this issue.

Comment: there is no such thing called "default Chinese input method"; there are quite a lot to choose from.